# Prove that $D^2/S^1\cong S^2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $D^2=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\cdot x\leq1\}$, $S^1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\cdot x=1\}$ and $S^2=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:x\cdot x=1\}$.

Let $q:D^2\rightarrow S^2$ given by $re^{i\theta}\mapsto (\sin{\pi r} \cos{\theta},\sin{\pi r}\sin{\theta},\cos{\pi r})$.

Verify that $D^2/S^1\cong S^2$.

I figured that if $q$ is continuous surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, then $q$ is a quotient map and thus the homeomorphism as required.

I'm not sure how to prove that details surrounding this proof such as: $q$'s continuity, $q$'s surjection, $D^2$'s compactness and $S^2$'s Hausdorffnesss.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $X$ is a topological space, and ${\sim} \subseteq X \times X$ is an equivalence relation, then $X/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to a space $Y$ if there is a quotient map $q : X \to Y$ such that $$(\forall x_1,x_2 \in X) \quad q(x_1) = q(x_2) \iff x_1 \sim x_2.$$

Indeed, by "$\Longleftarrow$" we can define a map $\overline{q} : X/{\sim} \to Y$ via $\overline{q}([x]_\sim) := q(x)$, and "$\Longrightarrow$" says that $\overline{q}$ is injective. Surjectivity follows from the one of $q$, and continuity follows from the fact that $\overline{q} \circ \pi = q$ is continuous, where $\pi : X \to X/{\sim}$ is the canonical quotient map: $\pi(x) := [x]_{\sim}$. Finally, it is a homeomorphism since if $U$ is an open set of $X/{\sim}$ (meaning that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$), then $\overline q(U)$ is open in $Y$ because $q^{-1}(\overline q(U))$ is open in $X$ (and $q$ is a quotient).

---

If $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then the symbol $X/A$ denotes the quotient space $X/{\sim}$ where for $x_1,x_2 \in X$ we write $x_1 \sim x_2$ when $x_1 = x_2$ or both $x_1,x_2 \in A.$

Thus, you only need to verify the following: if $x_1,x_2 \in D^2$, then $$q(x_1) = q(x_2) \iff x_1 = x_2 \textrm{ or } x_1,x_2 \in S^1.$$